# UK Standard Visitor visa for wife and 3-year-old daughter

Tags: indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, family

I am resident of India but in UK since 2nd January 2016 on a Tier 2 Intra-company Transfer (ICT) short-term visa (six months) valid till 2nd July 2016. I am planning to bring my wife and daughter on a Tourist visa for three months 1 April to 30 June. We are planning to enjoy summer here and visit a few places.

Reading here, it looks as though tourist visas for wife and daughter are rejected in some cases.

Is it feasible to get [tourist visas](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview) for my wife and daughter?

Has anyone gone through this situation and obtained the visa without any issue?

What are the things I need to provide to apply for a tourist visa, to make sure it is approved?

I have sufficient liquid funds in my salary account.

My wife has to go back for sure in June, as she is doing her post graduation and her examinations are in July 2016.

Right now, I don't want to go for a T2 dependant visa because in the month of July my company is planning to convert my visa to Long-term ICT and they will sponsor my family as dependants so that they can join me in August.

Comment: They issue these types of visas all the time, thousands of them. Indeed some get refused, but is there something specific about your wife's circumstances that lead you to believe she would be refused? Did you read https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview

Comment: Thanks for your response. My wife is a house wife. So she is fully dependent on me. I read in the forum that sometimes they rejected few cases like this and asked to apply dependent visa. 
I have read https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview completely and no where it says that T2 visa holders dependent wife can not apply for tourist visa.

Comment: The forum was wrong.  Your wife can certainly apply for a visit.  And yes, applications that are not wrapped tight will get refused.  For your other questions, you should read the guidance and stay away from forums.